# How do I get the First and last day of a month using month id in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have monthId say 4 for April and Year as Current Year , Now how do I get the First and last date of month 4 ??

Comment: _First and last date of month 4_: First = `01.monthId.Year` and Last = `DATEADD(day, -1, '01.monthId+1.Year')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DECLARE @monthId int  = 4
DECLARE @Year int = YEAR (GETDATE())
```

For Last Day Of month using monthid

```
 SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'' +CONVERt(VARCHAR(5),@Year)+ '-' + CONVERt(VARCHAR(5),@monthId) + '-01')+1 ,0))
```

For First Day Of month using monthid

```
 SELECT DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'' +CONVERt(VARCHAR(5),@Year)+ '-' + CONVERt(VARCHAR(5),@monthId) + '-01'),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL 2012+ you could use `datefromparts` and `eomonth` like the following query:

```
DECLARE @Year int = 2017,
      @Month int = 5
SELECT datefromparts(@Year, @Month, 1) AS TheFirstDateOfMonth,
     eomonth(datefromparts(@Year, @Month, 1)) AS TheFirstDateOfMonth
```

For the older version, you could use `dateadd`

```
SELECT  
    dateadd(month, @Month - 1, CAST(@Year AS varchar(4)) + '0101') AS TheFirstDateOfMonth,
    dateadd(day, -1 , dateadd(month, @Month , CAST(@Year AS varchar(4)) + '0101')) AS TheLastDateOfMonth
```